# php a better way of calculating number of days

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

**Home controller:**

```
//my query in repository
 public function Available (){
 $Sql= ' SELECT DISTINCT 
        a.property_id, a.date, a.minimum_stay,
        a.maximum_stay,a.quantity,
        p.duration, p.persons, p.amount, 
        p.extra_person_price, p.minimum_stay AS price_minimum_stay, 
        p.maximum_stay AS price_maximum_stay, p.weekdays 
        FROM availabilities AS a 
        JOIN prices AS p 
        ON a.property_id=p.property_id 
        WHERE a.minimum_stay >0 
        AND a.maximum_stay < 22 
        AND a.date >= p.period_from 
        AND a.date <= p.period_till

 ';
    class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */

    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $hotel_information = $this->retrieveInformationFromDB();

        return $this->render('Home/index.html.twig', array(
                'hotel_information'=>$hotel_information
            )
        );
    }


    private function retrieveInformationFromDB(){
        $em= $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $availables = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Availabilities')->Available();
        $hotel_information=array();

        for($i = 0; $i< count($availables) ; $i++) {
            $date = $availables[$i]['date'];
            $duration = $availables[$i]['duration'];
            $amount = $availables[$i]['amount'];
            $extra_person_price = $availables[$i]['extra_person_price'];
            $persons = explode('|',$availables[$i]['persons']);

            $hotel_information_placeholder = $this->calculatePricePerPerson($persons, $extra_person_price, $date, $amount,$duration);
            $hotel_information = array_merge($hotel_information, $hotel_information_placeholder);

        }

        return $hotel_information;
    }

    private function calculatePricePerPerson($persons, $extra_person_price, $date, $amount,$duration){
        foreach ($persons as $person) {
            if ($person > 1) {
                $price_per_person[] = array(
                    "date" => $date,
                    "person" => $person,
                    "price_person" => number_format((($person * $extra_person_price) + $amount) / 100, 2, '.', ','),
                    "day2"=>number_format(((($person * $extra_person_price) + $amount)*2) / 100, 2, '.', ','),
                    "day3"=>number_format(((($person * $extra_person_price) + $amount)*3) / 100, 2, '.', ','),
                    "day4"=>number_format(((($person * $extra_person_price) + $amount)*4) / 100, 2, '.', ','),
                    "day5"=>number_format(((($person * $extra_person_price) + $amount)*5) / 100, 2, '.', ','),
                    "day6"=>number_format(((($person * $extra_person_price) + $amount)*6) / 100, 2, '.', ','),
                    "day7"=>number_format(((($person * $extra_person_price) + $amount)*7) / 100, 2, '.', ','),

                );

            } else {
                $price_per_person[] = array(
                    "date" => $date,
                    "person" => $person,
                    "price_person" => number_format($amount / 100, 2, '.', ','),
                    "day2"=>number_format(($amount * 2)/ 100, 2, '.', ','),
                    "day3"=>number_format(($amount * 3)/ 100, 2, '.', ','),
                    "day4"=>number_format(($amount * 4)/ 100, 2, '.', ','),
                    "day5"=>number_format(($amount * 5)/ 100, 2, '.', ','),
                    "day6"=>number_format(($amount * 6)/ 100, 2, '.', ','),
                    "day7"=>number_format(($amount * 7)/ 100, 2, '.', ',')

                );
            }
        }

        return $price_per_person;
    }
```

In function **private function calculatePricePerPerson** I am calculating the price for a number of person and number of days based on date. At the moment I have calculated like this. The problem is a calculating number of is from 1 to 21 so therefore my foreach loop get really long and it is really ugly. So My question is how can I do this in better and more efficient way.

Comment: Well use another loop then …?

Comment: then I will have 3 nested loops. Can you give an example please?

Comment: Normalize the table prices  first i see you use `explode('|',$availables[$i]['persons']);` ...  indicating bad design.. if you normalize the tables you can do the price calculation on your database as it should be

Comment: _“then I will have 3 nested loops”_ - so? You say that as if it would mean anything ... _“Can you give an example please?”_ - nah, first you try something and show us ... (You will need to use a temporary variable to assemble the data first, you can not do that in one go using `$price_per_person[] = array(...` any more.)

Comment: Number of persons for which this price is valid, separated by a pipe sign I can't normalize it. otherwise I could do in sql query. that is why i am asking.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Broe So I need to make another loop inside `foreach ($persons as $person)`. How can I let it show 21 items. So I mean is it something like this: **sum=0 for(i=0, $i <21, $++)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code has several redundant points that can be optimized.
The original code :

```
private function calculatePricePerPerson($persons, $extra_person_price, $date, $amount,$duration){
        foreach ($persons as $person) {
            if ($person > 1) {
                $price_per_person[] = array(
                    "date" => $date,
                    "person" => $person,
                    "price_person" => number_format((($person * $extra_person_price) + $amount) / 100, 2, '.', ','),
                    "day2"=>number_format(((($person * $extra_person_price) + $amount)*2) / 100, 2, '.', ','),
                    "day3"=>number_format(((($person * $extra_person_price) + $amount)*3) / 100, 2, '.', ','),
                    "day4"=>number_format(((($person * $extra_person_price) + $amount)*4) / 100, 2, '.', ','),
                    "day5"=>number_format(((($person * $extra_person_price) + $amount)*5) / 100, 2, '.', ','),
                    "day6"=>number_format(((($person * $extra_person_price) + $amount)*6) / 100, 2, '.', ','),
                    "day7"=>number_format(((($person * $extra_person_price) + $amount)*7) / 100, 2, '.', ','),

                );

            } else {
                $price_per_person[] = array(
                    "date" => $date,
                    "person" => $person,
                    "price_person" => number_format($amount / 100, 2, '.', ','),
                    "day2"=>number_format(($amount * 2)/ 100, 2, '.', ','),
                    "day3"=>number_format(($amount * 3)/ 100, 2, '.', ','),
                    "day4"=>number_format(($amount * 4)/ 100, 2, '.', ','),
                    "day5"=>number_format(($amount * 5)/ 100, 2, '.', ','),
                    "day6"=>number_format(($amount * 6)/ 100, 2, '.', ','),
                    "day7"=>number_format(($amount * 7)/ 100, 2, '.', ',')

                );
            }
        }

        return $price_per_person;
    }
```

At first glance, it seems that the codes in both your `if` and `else` blocks are quite similar, the only difference being the extra person thing. By focusing on that element, you can avoid having two times almost the same code :

```
private function calculatePricePerPerson($persons, $extra_person_price, $date, $amount,$duration){
        foreach ($persons as $person) {
            if ($person > 1) {
                $amount += $person * $extra_person_price;
            }
            $price_per_person[] = array(
                "date" => $date,
                "person" => $person,
                "price_person" => number_format($amount / 100, 2, '.', ','),
                "day2"=>number_format(($amount * 2)/ 100, 2, '.', ','),
                "day3"=>number_format(($amount * 3)/ 100, 2, '.', ','),
                "day4"=>number_format(($amount * 4)/ 100, 2, '.', ','),
                "day5"=>number_format(($amount * 5)/ 100, 2, '.', ','),
                "day6"=>number_format(($amount * 6)/ 100, 2, '.', ','),
                "day7"=>number_format(($amount * 7)/ 100, 2, '.', ',')
            );
        }
        return $price_per_person;
    }
```

Instead of filling the array in each branch of the `if`, the person price is added to `$amount`. The else becomes useless and the array is filled all at once since `$amount` has a different value depending on the case.

Much shorter, but it's not over. The entries `day2` to `day7` are almost identical, the only difference being the number at the end of the key and factor by which `$amount` is multiplyed. By chance, they are always the same in each line, so lets reduce it to a loop :

```
private function calculatePricePerPerson($persons, $extra_person_price, $date, $amount,$duration){
        foreach ($persons as $person) {
            if ($person > 1) {
                $amount += $person * $extra_person_price;
            }
            $tmp = array(
                "date" => $date,
                "person" => $person,
                "price_person" => number_format($amount / 100, 2, '.', ',')
            );
            for ($x = 2; $x <= 7; ++$x) {
                $tmp["day$x"] = number_format(($amount * $x)/ 100, 2, '.', ',');
            }
            $price_per_person[] = $tmp;
        }
        return $price_per_person;
    }
```

During this step, I created a temporary array that is filled with the *static* data, then a `for` loop which adds entries to `$tmp` for each number of day that has to be handled. The temporary array is then assigned to `$price_per_person[]` so that everything works as it did in the first version. And since the days are now handled buy a loop, you can increase or decrease the amount of days that have to be computed and diplayed simply by modifying the limit in the for - currently 7.

And that's about as short as you can get without losing clarity. Besides, by removing redundancy you can update your code at once instead of - trying to - update every occurence of the - roughly - same code.

Comment: Thanx alot for your answere

Comment: Can you help with my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45978170/symfony-calculate-number-of-days-based-on-date) I am really stock here. I can get a job if I make this