# Symfony calculate number of days based on date

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, calculator

I am trying to calculate price for number of days from 1-21 based on date.

### HomeController

```
$Sql = ' SELECT DISTINCT 
            a.property_id, a.date, a.minimum_stay,
            a.maximum_stay,a.quantity,
            a.arrival_allowed,a.departure_allowed,
            p.duration, p.persons, p.amount, 
            p.extra_person_price, p.minimum_stay AS price_minimum_stay, 
            p.maximum_stay AS price_maximum_stay, p.weekdays, 
            p.period_till, p.period_from,
            datediff(p.period_till, p.period_from) AS number_of_days
            FROM availabilities AS a 
            JOIN prices AS p 
            ON a.property_id=p.property_id 
            WHERE a.minimum_stay >0 
            AND a.maximum_stay < 22 
            AND a.date >= p.period_from 
            AND a.date <= p.period_till
     ';
        $Stm = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->prepare($Sql);
        $Stm->execute();
        return $Stm->fetchAll(PDOConnection::FETCH_ASSOC);




    public function CalculatePrice($persons, $extra_person_price, $date, $amount, $duration, $period_till, $period_from)
    {
        //loop through persons
        foreach ($persons as $person) {
           //calculate price for persons
            if ($person > 1) {
                $amount += $person * $extra_person_price;
            }
            //array to link parameters with database fields
            $tmp = array(
                "date" => $date,
                "person" => $person,
                "price_person" => number_format($amount / 100, 2, '.', ',')
            );
            //loop through $tmp an add value from 2 to 21 to day an add this to $tmp array with calculated value
            //$x=$number_of_days;
            //$days = (strtotime($period_till) - strtotime($period_from)) / (60 * 60 * 24);

    for ($x = 1; $x <= 21; ++$x) {
                if ($x >1) {
                    $tmp["day$x"] = $tmp["day".($x-1)] + number_format($amount  / 100, 2, '.', ',');
                    //number_format(($amount * $x) / 100, 2, '.', ',');
                } else {
                    $tmp["day$x"] = "0.00";
                }

            $price_per_person[] = $tmp;
        }

        return $price_per_person;
    }
```

I am also calculating price for number of persons but that part is good. Right now I have made a for loop and stored numbers from 1 to 21 for number of days see my second for loop in `function CalculatePrice`. But this part not good I need to calculate this based on date. for example:
Regularly price for most of days is 123 Euro. let say on 3 September a day cost 250 euro and on 7 September it cost 300 Euro. So let say A person want to stay for 5 days and he arrives at 3 September so the calculation will be: 250 + 123 + 123 + 123 + 300 = 919 Euro.
But I need this to be based on date. I have tried with period_from and period_til but so far no luck. Can someone give an example or some useful hints how I can do this in a for loop like my second for loop.

Comment: your last for loop seems to assume a fixed price. i would suggest that you set `$tmp["day2"]` manually and do `$tmp["day$x"] = $tmp["day".($x-1)] + $price_of_the_day;` for all days >2 (do formatting when you output). then find a way to calculate the price for that day $x (start_date + $x, use date functions).

Comment: thanx, but what do you mean with `$price_of_the_day`, do you mean commented variable $day?

Comment: I mean, `$price_of_the_day` is the **price** of the day (stay) `$date` plus `$x` days. of course that's something that you have to calculate somehow, but I think this shouldn't be hard.

Comment: @T. Abdelmalek I have solved this question based on the theory T. Abdelmalek gave me. I made an array and stored date and price of each date in and loped through. The answer has been deleted somehow I don't know how to mark as solved.

Comment: @T. Abdelmalek Can you help with this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45999826/php-reset-calculation-if-boolean-is-true)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this question based on the theory T. Abdelmalek gave me. I made an array and stored date and price of each date in and loped through. The answer has been deleted somehow I don't know how to mark as solved

Answer (score 0):

You can use `date_diff` like that:

```
First date = $leave->getLeaveFrom();

    Second date = $leave->getLeaveTo();
    $diff = date_diff($leave->getLeaveFrom(),$leave->getLeaveTo());

Results = var_dump($diff);
```